# How to retrieve topic names from a Telegram supergroup using Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, telethon

I have a supergroup on telegram and the group is divided into about ten topics. 
I'm looking for a way to list the topic names in the terminal, but I get the error "Supergroup contains no topic information"

I create an app from https://my.telegram.org/apps and I try with this python code

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel, InputMessageID

api_id = 99999999
api_hash = 'b5b09783707618xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
phone_number = '+39xxxxxxxxxx'

group_id = -100xxxxxxxxxx  

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def get_topics():
    try:
        await client.start()
        entity = await client.get_entity(group_id)
        messages = await client.get_messages(entity, limit=100)

        topics = []
        for msg in messages:
            if msg.reply_to_msg_id is not None:
                try:
                    msg_ref = await client.get_messages(entity, ids=InputMessageID(id=msg.reply_to_msg_id))
                    if msg_ref and msg_ref.from_id == entity.id:
                        topics.append(msg.reply_to_msg_id)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Errore: {e}")

        return topics
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Errore: {e}")
        return None

async def main():
    topics = await get_topics()
    if topics:
        print("Lista dei topic presenti nel supergruppo:")
        for topic in topics:
            print(topic)
    else:
        print("The supergroup contains no topic information.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I get this error

**The supergroup contains no topic information**

I attempted to retrieve the list of topic names in my Telegram supergroup using the provided Python code. I expected the code to successfully fetch the topic information and print the list of topics in the terminal. However, when I ran the code, it resulted in the error message "The supergroup contains no topic information." I have already verified that the supergroup does have multiple topics, but the code seems unable to retrieve them.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the limited support for topics in Telegram's API or the way topics are handled in the supergroup. I tried to identify topics by checking if a message is a reply to another message, but this approach might not always work reliably.

If anyone has insights or solutions to retrieve topic information from a supergroup in Telegram using Python, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly useless. there is already a [dedicated request](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/get_forum_topics.html) for getting all topics of chat in chunks of 100, no need to get chat messages, an example code:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetForumTopicsRequest

api_id = 99999999
api_hash = "b5b09783707618xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
phone_number = "+39xxxxxxxxxx"

group_id = -100xxxxxxxxxx

client = TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash)


async def get_topics():
    try:
        topics = []
        date, offset, offset_topic, total = 0, 0, 0, 0
        while True:
            r = await client(
                GetForumTopicsRequest(
                    channel=group_id,
                    offset_date=date,
                    offset_id=offset,
                    offset_topic=offset_topic,
                    limit=100,
                )
            )
            if not total:
                total = r.count
            topic_list = r.topics
            if not topic_list or len(topics) >= total:
                break

            topics.extend(topic_list)
            last = topic_list[-1]

            offset_topic, offset = last.id, last.top_message
            date = {m.id: m.date for m in r.messages}.get(offset, 0)

        return total, topics
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Errore: {type(e).__name__}: {e}")
        return None, None


async def main():
    await client.start()
    total, topics = await get_topics()
    if topics:
        print("Lista dei topic presenti nel supergruppo:")
        print("Total topics:", total)
        for i, topic in enumerate(topics, start=1):
            print(f"{i} - ID: {topic.id} — {topic.title}")
    else:
        print("The supergroup contains no topic information.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: thanks, I take a look telethon documentation but is there also a method to list filenames of a specific topic ?

Comment: You'll need to pass top_msg_id in [messages.searchRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/search.html) if you want to get media list. set the filter or media type you want

Comment: I'm sorry, but after the Telegram update your solution no longer works, can you to take a look please? If you can both for a version where you list the topics, and for listing the last 10 posts of a supergroup topic, for example of a topic called "Comics" - I don't know why your solution doesn't work anymore, until 2 days ago it worked